# Python3 Extracting only emails from csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, extract

I have written a working script that extracts information from a .csv file. However, when extracted, it prints out all information instead of the emails when I wrote the code to specifically look for @ symbols.

```
 #!/bin/python3
    import re
    def print_csv():
            in_file = open('sample._data.csv', 'rt')
            for line in in_file:
                    if re.findall(r'(.*)@(.*).(.*)', line):
                            print(line)
    print_csv()
```

Here's a sample of the output:

```
"Carlee","Boulter","Tippett, Troy M Ii","8284 Hart St","Abilene","Dickinson","KS",67410,"785-347-1805","785-253-7049","carlee.boulter@hotmail.com","http://www.tippetttroymii.com"

"Thaddeus","Ankeny","Atc Contracting","5 Washington St #1","Roseville","Placer","CA",95678,"916-920-3571","916-459-2433","tankeny@ankeny.org","http://www.atccontracting.com"

"Jovita","Oles","Pagano, Philip G Esq","8 S Haven St","Daytona Beach","Volusia","FL",32114,"386-248-4118","386-208-6976","joles@gmail.com","http://www.paganophilipgesq.com"

"Alesia","Hixenbaugh","Kwikprint","9 Front St","Washington","District of Columbia","DC",20001,"202-646-7516","202-276-6826","alesia_hixenbaugh@hixenbaugh.org","http://www.kwikprint.com"

"Lai","Harabedian","Buergi & Madden Scale","1933 Packer Ave #2","Novato","Marin","CA",94945,"415-423-3294","415-926-6089","lai@gmail.com","http://www.buergimaddenscale.com"

"Brittni","Gillaspie","Inner Label","67 Rv Cent","Boise","Ada","ID",83709,"208-709-1235","208-206-9848","bgillaspie@gillaspie.com","http://www.innerlabel.com"

"Raylene","Kampa","Hermar Inc","2 Sw Nyberg Rd","Elkhart","Elkhart","IN",46514,"574-499-1454","574-330-1884","rkampa@kampa.org","http://www.hermarinc.com"

"Flo","Bookamer","Simonton Howe & Schneider Pc","89992 E 15th St","Alliance","Box Butte","NE",69301,"308-726-2182","308-250-6987","flo.bookamer@cox.net","http://www.simontonhoweschneiderpc.com"

"Jani","Biddy","Warehouse Office & Paper Prod","61556 W 20th Ave","Seattle","King","WA",98104,"206-711-6498","206-395-6284","jbiddy@yahoo.com","http://www.warehouseofficepaperprod.com"

"Chauncey","Motley","Affiliated With Travelodge","63 E Aurora Dr","Orlando","Orange","FL",32804,"407-413-4842","407-557-8857","chauncey_motley@aol.com","http://www.affiliatedwithtravelodge.com"
```

What I'm trying to do is get the output to look like a list of emails. I have trouble with filtering out the other content from the csv file.

Comment: It prints the entire line because you instruct it to. But I see a possible field of further exploration: you use a `csv` file and so you should look into the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for that. That way you don't *need* to scan an entire line of data, but only the specific field you are interested in.

Comment: Please see my response below and mark it as the answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned aboce, you should be able to use the built in csv library. If the file is csv then it should have a structured format and even if it doesn't have column names, you should be able to pull it by column position. Per your sample data, you can get the correct column by position. Please check out the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

```
>>> import os
>>> import csv
>>> with open('sample._data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print(row[10])

    # output:   
carlee.boulter@hotmail.com
tankeny@ankeny.org
joles@gmail.com
alesia_hixenbaugh@hixenbaugh.org
lai@gmail.com
bgillaspie@gillaspie.com
rkampa@kampa.org
flo.bookamer@cox.net
jbiddy@yahoo.com
chauncey_motley@aol.com
```